# How to forward from servlet to another servlet located in separate package?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect, error-handling

I am unable to `forward` the request to another servlet which is present inside different package.

Here's the effective **code of sender's servlet:**

```
RequestDispatcher rDispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/RecieverServlet");
rDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Here's the **directory structure:**

```
Source Packages --> servlets.senderServ.SenderServlet.java
Source Packages --> servlets.a.b.RecieverServlet.java

//a and senderserv are subpackages of servlet package
//b is subpackage of a package
```

The url: `/RecieverServlet` is not working and i am getting `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` error.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you give to the `getRequestDispatcher()` method does not refer to the servlet class name, but to its mapping.

You can define the servlet mapping either by:

1. Declaring it int the `web.xml`
2. Using the `@WebServlet` annotation.

Comment: how to define servlet mapping by `@WebServlet` annotation?

Comment: Annotate your servlet class with `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/RecieverServlet")`. Note that it requires at least Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this use Servlet context

```
 ServletContext context = getServletContext().getContext("package name of other servlet");
        RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/name of servlet");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.xml config file for `/RecieverServlet` mapping. Make sure the right servlet(package doen't matter) mapped to this url